# how to achieve this with react.js?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hi I want to build toggle box which have three columns in a row like below.

[image]

the dummy data looks like below

```
export const topicDummy: TopicData = 
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: '넷플릭스',
      url: 'netflix'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: '어도비',
      url: 'adobe'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: '왓챠',
      url: 'watcha'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: '방돌이/방순이',
      url: 'roommate'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: '신문구독',
      url: 'newspaper'
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: '공동구매',
      url: 'share'
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: 'KTX',
      url: 'train'
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: '기타',
      url: 'etc'
    },
  ]
```

---

To achieve this, 
I built function which return jsx elements. 
But I don't want to build function every times when I want to build box like this.

how can I do with this?

Comment: What is a toggle box?

Comment: toggle box is like a visible menu box when you click some buttons in navigation bar, and it's gone when you click outside the box.

Comment: Why don't you make it a component and just pass it the props it should render?

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of styleing this will look just like the one in your image. It's written in JavaScript not TypeScript, but i'm pretty sure you know how to change that. (I never used TypeScript).

If you want this not to re-render each time you should probably read the documentation of [React.memo()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate).

```
const ToggleMenuBox = ({ goToLink }) => topicDummy.map(item =>
    <div key={item.id} onClick={goToLink(item.url)} style={styles.element}>
        {item.name}
    </div>
)

export default () => {

    const goToLink = url => () => {
        console.log("Redirecting to", url)
    }

    return (
        <div style={styles.root}>
            <ToggleMenuBox goToLink={goToLink}/>
        </div>
    )
}

const styles = {
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: 'calc(100% - 40px)',
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 5,
        margin: '0 auto',
    },
    element: {
        width: '33%',
        textAlign: 'center',
        cursor: 'pointer'
    }
}
```